# Can't start a program from windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Some days ago I noticed this problem, and I can't find a way to solve it. I've tried almost everything people sugested on foruns, but I couldn't get it solved.

[image]

This is what my start menu looks like right now. If I click on Google Chrome or any other software on the right and on the left if will not open. I click and nothing happens, this very strange.

The only software I can open is windows related, like that 3D Builder, or the calculator or the calendar.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had disabled some options with ShellExView while trying to remove some context menu bugs, that shouldn't been disabled.

Comment: You can select your own answer as the official solution.  It might prove to be valuable for others who decide to _disable some options_ in their spare time and encounter the same problem.

Comment: I know @Run5k, but I can only acept it after 2 days

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for getting back to us and explaining the root cause of the problem, we definitely appreciate your time & effort!